# can two primary keys be refer to the same attribute in another table

Tags: database, primary-key

Can two primary keys  refer to the same attribute in another table  for example 
customer id from table customer and user id from table user which refer to field id in table billing and i think i can differentiate between  them by adding type field.

Comment: Properly punctuated, almost anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why not but I also see your adding confusion for the next guy that has to work on this.  Why not treat them separately with customer ID and User ID as different values?  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but probably shouldn't. It is generally clearer to have linking tables instead; for example, if you have "customers", "users", and "billing" tables, have "customer_billing" and "user_billing" tables, rather than having a customer-or-user-id and type in the billing table.

Comment: Thank you but adding tow tables with  much common similarities is that right ?

Comment: Most of the billing related data would be in the "billing" table; the "customer_billing" table would just have a customer_id and billing_id in it, while the "user_billing" table would just have a user_id and billing_id.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to have one supertype table containing the key for all users and customers. Reference the supertype table from your billing table.